# Django form submit with ajax form.serialize()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
        user = authenticate(username=mobile, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/owner/?own=" + str(user.id))
```

**login.html**

```
$('.login-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/login/',
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize()
          success: function(data) {
 });
});
```

i'm getting error:

Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
[20/Oct/2018 04:41:30] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: Can you post the config from your `urls.py` for your `login` function?

Comment: this code is working when I'm sending post data manually.But with form.serialize()  it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a name conflict between your  login function and the django built in login function, rename your function to something else like user_login.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're missing csrf token? Try passing Django csrf token into your JQuery.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).